# i-v graph, how to find current and its behavior

Tags: circuit-analysis, graph

[image: schematic diagram]

I have this circuit and I am trying to make a i-v characteristic chart.  I see that it has 2A as displayed, so would I split it between the 4 ohm resistor and the left side element?

In addition, I am confused at exactly what I am supposed to graph based on the resistors shown.

Comment: This looks like homework, so you should ask your instructor "what I am supposed to graph". There is no reason to believe, just by inspection, that the current *i* would be 2A. If you want more help, please make an attempt yourself and tell us specifically where you get stuck.

Comment: Iin=Vin/4+2A thus V vs I can  be plotted.

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what the task is, but I'll take a stab.

If the problem says something like, "plot \$i\$ and \$v\$ for the following circuit," then what that essentially means is: pretend there's an element between the two nodes on the left of the circuit.  If that element has zero volts across it, calculate the current that flows through it.  Mark that data point on your i-v graph.  Now pretend that element has 1 Volt across it and calculate how much current flows through it; mark that data point.  Repeat this until you have a full characteristic curve.

Many times people will draw a "fictitious" ideal voltage source  at the two nodes to help them visualize where the "pretend" voltage comes from.

Comment: yes that is what i meant. thanks. so i would take the 2A and have it split between 4ohm resistor and the element correct?

Comment: That's exactly right.  The reasoning for this stems from KCL.